# Lenz's law to determine the direction of induced current

Tags: generator, homework

I came across this MCQ in my text book, it says:

> To determine the direction of current induced in AC generators, we use....
>
> (i) Lenz's law (ii) Fleming's right hand rule (iii) both of them

Frequently, I use Fleming's right hand rule to determine the direction of current, but lenz's law refers to the principle that the current will be in opposite direction to the change in the flux, and that's the principle upon which the generator works.  So, this multiple-choice question made me confused, and I thought choice (iii) might be the correct answer, so could anyone help me?

Comment: I don't like either of them - it assumes there is a load on the generator that is taking current i.e. the induced voltage is producing current. I don't like the term "induced current" because it is voltage that is induced and, when there is a load, that gives rise to current.

Comment: I agree with Andy.  Change in flux, induces voltage, which will cause a current to flow.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleming%27s_right-hand_rule) _Fleming's right-hand rule (for generators) shows the direction of induced current when a conductor moves in a magnetic field_.